# The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt

When I run `sudo apt update` on my Ubunutu 16.10 I get the following error message:

```
E:The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release' does not have a Release file.
```